# WPF C# DataBinding Error Visisbility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I'm desperate person... 
Here is my problem. I have a container which contains usercontrol (editor for my referencial).

The content of my container is bind by a property "Editor" which return the correct usercontrol according to a type of selected object.

Here is my container code :

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" Grid.Row="1">
    <UserControl Content="{Binding Editor, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Border>
```

Here is my selectedobject property :

```
public object SelectedEntity
{
    get { return _SelectedEntity; }
    set
    {
        Set("SelectedEntity", ref _SelectedEntity, value);
        Editor = (value != null) ? Editors[value.GetType()] : null;

        if (Editor != null)
        {
             Editor.SetEditable(true);
             Editor.SetValue(SelectedEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

When I select my object, the correct Editor is finded and applied.
But in the view, the inner control of the editor isn't visible (Label, Textbox and button).

In the output I found this exception :

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedEntity' property not found on 'object' ''GommageEditor' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedEntity; DataItem='GommageEditor' (Name=''); target element is 'Grid' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

I'm not sur about this exception, but when I comment the datacontext declaration in the constructor of the usercontrol editor, It is then visible...

```
/// <summary>
///     Constructeur par défaut
/// </summary>
public UserControlEditor()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    /* When i comment this line innercontrols of usercontrol are visible */
    DataContext = new UserControlEditorViewModel();
}
```

Have an idea ? solution ? 
Thanks in advance...

I'm using Galasoft MVVM ligth for MVVM pattern, and Mahapps Template for my controls.

EDIT :
I use one trigger on my usercontrol, to override the Textbox style when i'm in non editing mode.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Editing}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Type de gommage" Style="{StaticResource Title5}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Gommage.Type}"/>

    <Label Content="Acronyme du gommage" Style="{StaticResource Title5}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Gommage.Acronyme}"/>

    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
            Content="Enregistrer"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Editing}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is Editor a dependency property ? The exception is complaining about the binding erorr in xmal of SelectedEditor/Editor. Are you using any triggers ? as the problem property is NoTarget, which should be related to the triggers in wpf

Comment: I add the content of my Usercontrol to the post. Editor is just an Property. There is a difference between **dependency property** and **property** ?

Comment: UserControls should NEVER have ViewModels designed for them.  That's because of issues **just like this**.  Remove this ViewModel.  Put all UI code in your UserControl's codebehind.  Think about this--Why does the TextBox not have a TextBoxViewModel?  Why isn't there a ComboBoxViewModel?  Now **why does your UserControl have one??**  MVVM != no codebehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake !

In the container of my editor, I was setting a style with **datatrigger** on **SelectedEntity**.

If I **remove this style**, it worked fine ! :)

Thanks to cscmh99 !